# Checking Sentence Case in String

Tags: python, string

I wonder how to check for sentence case in string. I know about `isupper()` method that checks for any uppercase character. But what about sentence case? For example:

```
def check_string(string):
    <...>
    return result

check_string('This is a proper sentence case.')
True

check_string('THIS IS UPPER CASE')
False

check_string('This string is Clean')
False
```

Comment: `string[0].isupper() and string[1:].islower()`?

Comment: @MechanicPig So long as there are no proper nouns in the sentence...

Comment: @AKX If the rules are not so simple, OP may need some libraries for language processing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to solve a problem, there must be a **clear** specification. **How do you know** that the results should be as described?

Comment: Keep in mind that a `str` value is not necessarily a single sentence.

Answer (score 0):

A quick trick for this would be using [`capitalize()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_capitalize.asp) and check if it is equal to the original input:

```
def check_string(my_string):
    cap_string = my_string.capitalize()
    if (cap_string == my_string):
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: This fails for strings containing multiple sentences.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def check_string(string):
    sentences = string.split(".")
    for sentence in sentences:
        sentence = sentence.strip()
        if sentence and (not sentence[0].isupper() or any(filter(lambda x: x.isupper(), sentence[1:]))):
            return False
    return True
```